# Vue.jsの読み込み時にエラー: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js

Vue.jsなのですが、jsファイルが読み込まれず、現在そのまま`{{message}}`と記述されしまいます
コンソールには以下のエラーです
Hello Vueと表示させたいのですが、どうすれば良いでしょうか？

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

app/javascript/packs/main.js

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue'
  }
})
```

app/views/tops/index.html.erb

```
<div id="app">
  {{message}}
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="../../javascript/packs/main.js"></script>
```

Vue.js導入に参考にした記事

[既に動いてるRailsにVue.jsを導入する](https://off.tokyo/blog/%E6%97%A2%E3%81%AB%E5%8B%95%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8Brails%E3%81%ABvue-js%E3%82%92%E5%B0%8E%E5%85%A5%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/)

Comment: 試しに相対パスではなくて絶対パスで記述するとどうなりますか？

Comment: <script src="/javascript/packs/main.js"></script>　絶対パスでも変わりませんでした

Answer (score 1):

以下の記述で読み込めました。

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'main' %>
```